# dropdown value is not inserting as actual

Tags: javascript, html

If I select Yes, insert into query is taking as 11 in database:

```html
<td align="center">Offers in Hand :</td>
<td>
  <select name="Offers_in_Hand" id="Offers_in_Hand_Id" style="width: 250px" Required>
    <option selected></option>
    <option value="11">Yes</option>
    <option value="22">No</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

Comment: and what are you looking for ?? do you want to insert the "yes" ?

Comment: @Patil its obvious

Answer (score 0):

Change `option`s `value` to desired, in your case "Yes" & "No", like this:

(jQuery added only to confirm correct value is being captured)

```js
$("#Offers_in_Hand_Id").change(function() {
  var value = $("#Offers_in_Hand_Id").val();
  $("#test").html(value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td align="center">Offers in Hand :</td>
<td>
  <select name="Offers_in_Hand" id="Offers_in_Hand_Id" style="width: 250px" Required>
    <option selected></option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
  </select>
</td>
<span id="test"></span>
```